# CosmosDB - query for consumed RU/s programmatically?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to get information about **consumption of RU/second on the collection level**, unfortunately when I query for collection information with node.js documentdb module, with code like

```
var client = new DocumentDBClient(host, { masterKey: masterKey });
client.readCollection(collection._self, function(err, item) {
   if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log(item);
    }
});
```

I get only basic information like below

```
{ id: 'myCollection',
  indexingPolicy:
   { indexingMode: 'consistent',
     automatic: true,
     includedPaths: [ [Object] ],
     excludedPaths: [] },
  _rid: 'ku8SANRCfwA=',
  _ts: 1505295711,
  _self: 'dbs/ku8SAA==/colls/ku8SANRCfwA=/',
  _etag: '"00008b00-0000-0000-0000-59b8fd5f0000"',
  _docs: 'docs/',
  _sprocs: 'sprocs/',
  _triggers: 'triggers/',
  _udfs: 'udfs/',
  _conflicts: 'conflicts/' }
```

Is there any other way to get RU consumption information per collection? This data is available in the portal in **Metrics -> Throughput** blade, but how to get it through API is a mystery to me. **Azure Monitor** provides only a metric averaged on the whole database level, so using **Azure Monitor API** also isn't a way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be feasible in your scenario, but you could definitely roll your own solution with the use of some other Azure offerings. I agree that a native API for pulling RU consumption would be much more ideal.

If you wanted to roll your own you could do so through the use of Event Hubs and Stream Analytics. Write a small wrapper around your Cosmos queries that publishes their RU cost to your event hub (RU cost is returned from Cosmos with every operation you perform). From there, Stream Analytics has built in integration for ingesting messages from your Hub. It would be a matter of creating a simple query that aggregates RU cost in one second buckets. From there you could do all kinds of cool stuff including sending alerts at given thresholds or even triggering automatic scale operations in response to your realtime usage to optimize your Cosmos costs.

Depending on how heavily you leverage Cosmos and if you observe spikey workloads the cost savings of doing intelligent scaling would more than offset the additional spend for Event Hubs + Stream Analytics.

Comment: Interesting idea, it sounds crazy complex, but if this would be the only option... :) What is interesting is that those metrics are in the system, since they are presented through portal dashboards. It's just the API and Azure Monitor where I don't see them exposed...

Comment: Architecturally it might sound a bit complex but I think if you were to implement it you'd be surprised at how quickly and easily it came together. They're really powerful tools with relatively simple APIs for this sort of a use case. It is frustrating that those metrics are clearly available somewhere but the advantage of this approach would be much more realtime and actionable insights. The metrics in the portal don't offer the greatest granularity and can lag behind a little.

Comment: Seems you can now get the RUs consumed via a RESTful API, down to a per-minute rate: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/monitor-accounts#monitor-azure-cosmos-db-programmatically ; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-supported#request-unit-metrics . See metric TotalRequestUnits. My experiments suggested it was possible to retrieve RUs consumed/minute, down to the previous wholly completed minute.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the consumed RU/s using the @azure/arm-monitor and @azure/ms-rest-nodeauth packages.  You'll need to provide the caller (function app running in Azure if using MSI auth or a service principal) with 'API Management Service Reader' and 'Monitoring Reader' privileges on the resource group in the Azure portal.  The code looks something like this in TypeScript:

```html
import * as moment from 'moment'
import {
  loginWithAppServiceMSI
} from '@azure/ms-rest-nodeauth'
import {
  MonitorManagementClient, MonitorManagementModels
} from '@azure/arm-monitor'
import { MetricsListResponse } from '@azure/arm-monitor/esm/models'

// alternatively, you can use a service principal creds, @azure/ms-rest-nodeauth -> loginWithServicePrincipalSecretWithAuthResponse()
const credentials = await loginWithAppServiceMSI({
  msiEndpoint: process.env.MSI_ENDPOINT,
  msiSecret: process.env.MSI_SECRET,
  resource: 'https://management.azure.com/'
})
const now = moment()
const end = now.toISOString()
const start = now.subtract(1, 'minute').toISOString()
const client = new MonitorManagementClient(credentials, SUBSCRIPTION_ID)

const options: MonitorManagementModels.MetricsListOptionalParams = {
  metricnames: 'TotalRequestUnits',
  metricnamespace: 'Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts',
  filter: `CollectionName eq '${CONTAINER_NAME}'`,
  interval: 'PT1M',
  timespan: `${start}/${end}`
}
const url = `subscriptions/${SUBSCRIPTION_ID}/resourceGroups/${RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME}/providers/Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/${DATABASE_NAME}`
const response: MetricsListResponse = (await client.metrics.list(
  url,
  options
))
```